# Crossing MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql

I feel like this is something I can search for, but I don't know the correct terminology to go about it.

I have a SQL database that has a a few tables. One table stores caller logs for a softphone (agent_log), one table stores campaign information for what the people on the softphone are calling on (campaigns). Both tables have the column "campaign_id" that I can use to call to each other (I think). I need to relate these two tables so that I can have a sql query that would look like

```
SELECT * FROM agent_log WHERE active = 'Y';
```

Obviously it doesn't work because the column 'active' doesn't exist in that table, it exists in the campaigns table. Is there any simple way to go about this?

Comment: look into join http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: its always a good resource for beginners, never failed me :) http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: If this is a live DB, and you do not already have the knowledge to do something like this please stop for a moment. It is very easy to write a bad query when you are learning that is going to lock up tables and potentially impact other users. Do yourself, and your organization a favor and run through some tutorials, maybe push to do a SQL training if you are going to do this on a regular basis. If you are experimenting, do so on a development server. I have seen a single statement kill a live application for over 30min because  a join wasn't written correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id campaign_id exists in both table and assuming that there is a relation between table you can join them:

```
SELECT agent_log.campaign_id
FROM agent_log, campaigns
WHERE agent_log.campaign_id = campaigns.campaign_id 
      AND campaigns.active = 'Y'
```

if you like to use JOIN i suggest you spend some of your time to learn it.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is called a `JOIN` You would `JOIN` the tables using a field that is common between them, so for your tables it would be `campaign_id`.

```
SELECT *
FROM agent_log al
INNER JOIN campaigns c
    ON al.campaign_id = c.campaign_id
WHERE c.active = 'Y'
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM agent_log al
INNER JOIN campaigns c
    ON al.campaign_id = c.campaign_id
    AND c.active = 'Y'
```

I suggest you do some reading about `JOIN`s.  [The Visual Explanation of Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) is a great start.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM agent_log 
INNER JOIN campaigns ON agent_log.campaign_id = campaigns.campaign_id 
WHERE campaigns.active = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use a JOIN query like this

```
SELECT al.*
FROM agent_log as al
INNER JOIN campaigns as c
ON al.campaign_id = c.campaign_id
WHERE c.active = 'Y';
```

You need to make sure you have indexed on campaign_id field on both tables and the active field in the campaign table to make the query run efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

This should work without inner join

```
SELECT 
    agent_log.campaign_id 
FROM 
    agent_log,
    campaigns 
WHERE 
    agent_log.campaign_id = campaigns.campaign_id
AND
    campaigns.active = 'Y';
```